# Snap points me to a package that, in fact, doesn't exist. What's going on?

Tags: package-management, snap

So, I just did the following and it makes absolutely no sense to me. (Please ignore my custom $PS1).

Let's try to install Vs Code in a wrong way (the correct package name is `code`), and follow through snapd's suggestions:

```
(base) nagyg -> snap install vscode                                                                                     
error: snap "vscode" is not available on stable but is available to install on the following                            
       channels:                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
       candidate  snap install --candidate vscode                                                                       
       beta       snap install --beta vscode                                                                            
       edge       snap install --edge vscode                                                                            
                                                                                                                        
       Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not completely tested or                             
       implemented. Get more information with 'snap info vscode'.                                                       

(base) nagyg -> snap install --beta vscode                                                                              
error: snap "vscode" is not available on beta but is available to install on the following                              
       channels:                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
       edge       snap install --edge vscode                                                                            
                                                                                                                        
       Get more information with 'snap info vscode'.                                                                    
                                                                                                                        
(base) nagyg -> snap install --edge vscode                                                                          
error: snap "vscode" is not available on latest/edge but other tracks exist.                                            
                                                                                                                        
       Please be mindful that different tracks may include different features. Get more information                     
       with 'snap info vscode'.                                                                                         
                                                                                                                        
(base) nagyg -> snap info vscode                                                                                        
error: no snap found for "vscode"
```

...What?

The package `vscode` does not exist. I get this. But why does Snap make false statements, and points me to a nonexisting package on development channels? What is going on here?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this? Try `sudo snap refresh` first.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The command gives `all snaps are up to date`, and the situation is unchanged afterwards. I also just did an apt update-upgrade this morning.

Comment: You begin with a false assumption, and try to install the wrong package. Why not install the right package to begin with?

Comment: @ArturMeinild That's the whole point: a wrong package should outright fail, isn't it? I want to understand why Snap is pointing me to some nonexisting where, and stating that it exists, instead of telling me I'm stupid. Normally if I want to install a nonexisting package, I get `error: snap "njngi" not found`.

Comment: Without having any knowledge about this whatsoever, I would guess the reason is that the snap `vscode` existed at some point, and that there is some hidden data behind the now unused snap name. But it would be better to ask this on the [Snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/).

Comment: @ArturMeinild thanks for the suggestion, [I did it](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-points-me-to-a-package-that-in-fact-doesnt-exist-whats-going-on/26326). It's good if they know, this might be a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong command to install. It's a good idea to check the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/code) first, to make sure you got it right.

This is the correct command to install:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

If you want to know about the inner workings of the snap daemon and `snap` command, it would be better to ask on the [Snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/), where there is a chance the developers can answer your question.

Comment: I know it's a wrong command, as I mentioned in the beginning of my question. That's the whole point. The question is, why does Snap tell me the package exist on some channel, when it obviously doesn't?